# how to parse a DOM with jsdom from a node REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

I am trying to write some DOM-parsing code to run from a [node REPL environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798300/274677). Below is a SSCCE:

```
"use strict";

var jsdom = require("jsdom");

var html="<a></a>";

function parse(html, x) {
    jsdom.env(html, function(errors, window) {
        x.window = window;
    });
}

var x = {};
parse(html, x);
console.log(x.window);
```

The idea being that after calling the `parse` function I would have the parsed DOM available in my `x` object.

When I put the above code in a file `j.js` and load it from the REPL I get:

```
> .load j.js
> "use strict";
'use strict'
> var jsdom = require("jsdom");
undefined
> var html="<a></a>";
undefined
> function parse(html, x) {
...     jsdom.env(html, function(errors, window) {
.....         x.window = window;
.....     });
... }
undefined
> var x = {};
undefined
> parse(html, x);
undefined
> console.log(x.window);
undefined
undefined
>
```

Why does the code fail to assign the `x.window` property?

Comment: @jsalonen I am trying to, eventually, get the DOM object corresponding to the `html` variable and do some tree navigation in it. This is a SSCCE. Maybe there's a better way to get the DOM using `jsdom` I just came up with this `parse` function as a way to abstract away the `jsdom` logic and have a way to get to communicate the value to the calling context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsdom.env` callback gets evaluated asynchronously. This means that in most cases (probably always) `console.log(x.window)` gets executed before the `x.window = window;` assignment.

The easiest fix is to pass a callback function that you execute after the assignment:

```
...

function parse(html, x, done) {
    jsdom.env(html, function(errors, window) {
        x.window = window;
        done();
    });
}

var x = {};

parse(html, x, function() {
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: OK so basically, doing it this way, the object and argument `x` are superfluous. Is there an idiom one can use to transform this asynchronous interface to a synchronous interface like: `var window = parse(html)` ??

Comment: Yes indeed, you do not need to pass `x` as parameter to `parse` since it already is already visible from outer scope.

However, writing code like `var window = parse(html)` would require you to convert from async to sync, which is generally a bad idea in node: unless you use something like node-fibers (say via sync) you would block all other execution until synchronous parse is completed.

Personally, I would much rather try to go with the flow and adopt async programming style -- its the way node programs are typically written.